# Scientific Computing Library on iOS/Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, scientific-computing

I'm thinking of developing something on the iOS platform that would require some scientific libraries, for tasks such as solving roots for cubic/quartic polynomials, numerical root finding, optimization, etc. I'm wondering if people would know any good libraries that's compatible with iOS/Apple App Store.

I've tried to google around to no avail. GNU's Scientific Computing Library comes to mind, but too bad their licensing is not allowed on the app store...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

did you tried digging in Accelerate Framework?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreOSLayer/CoreOSLayer.html

Comment: Hi Raj, I was not aware of the framework, but I did a quick search. It doesn't seem to contain what I want (i.e., complex number polynomials root finding)....or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps CodeCogs (http://www.codecogs.com) will do what you need? Components are available for non-GPL licensing, although you will have to pay.

Also, CCMATH (http://freshmeat.net/projects/ccmath/) is LGPL licensed.